# Are there data usage limitations with Google Cloud Compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've got a E2 Micro instance running on Google Compute Engine at the moment.

Although it won't be using bandwidth quickly (expecting a maximum of 600Mbps), it will probably be using a lot of bandwidth in total (expecting around 10TB a month)

Are there any limitations to how much bandwidth my VM can use in total per month, or am I only going to be limited by speed?

Answer (score 0):

You will be limited by your credit limit. Review network pricing. Internet egress bandwidth is apx $0.12 to $0.23 per GB. 10,000 GB is $1,200 to $2,300 per month.

Search for "Internet egress rates" at this link:

[Google Cloud networking pricing](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing)

Note: for new accounts, IIRC your payment method will be charged at $100.00. Double-check how your account is setup.

> For example, if your Cloud Billing threshold is $100.00, and you have not yet incurred any costs for the month, you might see a message that says Your entire $100.00 payment threshold is available.
>
> or
>
> "You'll be charged when your balance reaches $1000.00 or 30 days after
> your last automatic payment, whichever comes first."

[Find out your Cloud Billing account type and charging cycle](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-cycle)